# how to automatically set header to all files inside /storage/ folder?

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

My frontend is trying to `fetch()` an image from my API, which usually handles my CORS. Because it directly requests the image, circumventing the API, I receive this issue: (which makes complete sense why)

```sh
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://my-api.test/storage/media/1/15/poster.jpg' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I need to adjust my Nginx settings so that any file requested living under the `/storage/` path will have this header added.

I must be misunderstanding parts of how I should configure Nginx in this case, because I was believing that this location-block should have worked:

```sh
location /storage/ {
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
}
```

Oddly, it returns a "404 status":

```sh
curl -I https://my-api.test/storage/test-media/butterfly.jpg
HTTP/2 404
server: nginx/1.19.4
date: Tue, 17 Nov 2020 06:57:23 GMT
content-type: image/jpeg
content-length: 116501
etag: "5f6045f4-1c715"
```

On the other hand, if I disable the location-block condition:

```sh
#location /storage/ {
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
#}
```

The header then is properly added:

```sh
curl -I https://my-api.test/storage/test-media/butterfly.jpg
HTTP/2 200
server: nginx/1.19.4
date: Tue, 17 Nov 2020 07:00:53 GMT
content-type: image/jpeg
content-length: 116501
last-modified: Tue, 15 Sep 2020 04:41:24 GMT
etag: "5f6045f4-1c715"
access-control-allow-origin: *
accept-ranges: bytes
```

Any help would be truly appreciated!

*edit 1*

I am not sure whether it makes a difference, but the "storage" folder is a symlink.

*edit 2*

The nginx error:

```
2020/11/17 12:45:50 [error] 64990#0: *1 open() "/storage/media/1/1/turtle.jpg" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "HEAD /storage/media/1/1/turtle.jpg HTTP/1.1", host: "my-api.test"
```

When I try to visit the URL in the browser `my-api.test/storage/media/1/1/turtle.jpg` it returns the image and not a 404.

Comment: laravel 8 have `cors.php` you can add  `'paths' => ['api/*', 'http://localhost:8080'],`

Comment: True, and there's no problem with Laravel CORS, because the Laravel API is never touched during this request. When I make use of the API, Laravel CORS works as expected

Comment: this post describes my exact same scenario https://zaengle.com/blog/configuring-cors-for-laravel-public-storage

Comment: `api/*` comes with by default i m telling you add your client url which are try to access that resource so laravel allow them to access

Comment: I know how to make use of Laravel CORS. Make heavy use of it throughout the whole application. The issue here is that it is *not* going through Laravel, so the Laravel `HandleCors` middleware is never triggered. It directly requests the image from a frontend that is not on the same domain as the API

Comment: Sounds weird. I just checked the same configuration and it is works as expected (nginx 1.17.8, HTTP/1.1).

Comment: @IvanShatsky I know, it seems really odd. I get a "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found" but other headers are "Content-Type: image/jpeg", so it does "find" the image. Hmm...

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem was rather simple:

```
location /storage/ {
    root '/Users/chrisbreuer/code/my-api/public';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "*" always;
}
```

As you can see, the location-block is now adding a root which is where the "storage" folder lives in.

In my case, I was using Laravel Valet and when you have a secure site, you would need to adjust the nginx config file which is located in this path: `~/.config/valet/Nginx/meema-api.test`.

Now, simply run `valet restart` and all files requested from within the storage-folder will have the header included.